# How to add a pre-build step to project via the Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, ide, pre-build-event

Is there an easy way to add a pre-build/post-build step to a project via the Visual Studio IDE? I know I can edit the .csproj/.*proj file - what I want to know is if there is a way right from the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-clic on the project name in the solution explorer and clic on "properties" in the popup menu. In the window that shows up, go to the section "configuration properties / Buid events" (or something similar: my IDE is in french). You will then have the choice:

- Pre-build events,
- Pre-link events,
- Post-build events.